# converting webpage into jpeg image using java

Tags: java, jpeg, image-capture, webpage-screenshot

I am building a web application, in Java, where i want the whole screenshot of the webpage, if i give the URL of the webpage as input.

The basic idea i have is to capture the display buffer of the rendering component..I have no idea of how to do it..
plz help..

Answer (score 3):

There's a little trick I used for this app:

[count down demo app http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/742/capturadepantalla201004wd.png](http://vimeo.com/6636018)
<sub>*Java application featuring blog.stackoverflow.com page ( click on image to see the demo video )*</sub>

The problem is you need to have a machine devoted to this.

So, the trick is quite easy.

- Create an application that takes as
  argument the URL you want to fetch.
- Then open it with `Desktop.open( url
  )`  that will trigger the current
  webbrowser.
- And finally take the screenshot with
  java.awt.Robot and save it to diks.

Something like:

```
 class WebScreenShot {
     public static void main( String [] args ) {
         Desktop.getDesktop().open( args[0] );
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         Image image = robot.createScreenCapture( getScreenResolutionSize() );
         saveToDisk( image );
     }
  }
```

This solution is far from perfect, because it needs the whole OS, but if you can have a VM devoted to this app, you can craw the web and take screenshots of it quite easy.

The problem of having this app as a non-intrusive app is that up to this date, there is not a good html engine renderer for Java.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work on [headless](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html) servers.

Comment: @Balusc Yeap, actually I ran it as an standalone application.

Answer (score 3):

For a pure-java solution that can scale to support concurrent rendering, you could use a java HTML4/CSS2 browser, such as [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp), that provides a Swing component for the GUI. When you instantiate this component, you can call it's paint(Graphics g) method to draw itself into an off-screen image

```
E.g.
Component c = ...; // the browser component
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), TYPE_INT_RGB)
Graphics2d g = bi.createGraphics();    
c.paint(g);
```

You can then use the java image API to save this as a JPG.

```
JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createEncoder(new FileOutputStream("screen.jpg"));
enncoder.encode(bi);  // encode the buffered image
```

Java-based browsers typically pale in comparison with the established native browsers. However, as your goal is static images, and not an interactive browser, a java-based browser may be more than adequate in this regard.